# mySQL update string value by appending its current value

Tags: mysql

I know I can update the value of a number in mysql using this syntax:

```
update table set age = age + 5 where ID = 2;
```

But I cannot figure out how to **append** the value of a string, like so:

```
update table set textField = textField + ", California" where ID = 2;
```

Where textField is "Arizona, New Mexico, New York" and I'm trying to add `", California"` to it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat `update table set textField = concat(textfield, ", California") WHERE ID = 2;`

Comment: booya.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET textField = CONCAT(textfield, ", California") WHERE ID = 2;

[My SQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Works in select statements too like:
SELECT CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName) CustomerName FROM customers;

Comment: Copying and pasting a comment is not a productive answer. If you can elaborate on the comment to turn it into a worthwhile answer, by all means do so (providing proper attribution to the original commenter of course.)

Comment: I answered within like a minute of the comment, when I saw there were zero answers. This is a very simple solution, I didn't even see the comment.  What I copy and pasted was the original poster's example and then just added the concat() portion to his example.  Don't assume the worst of people, especially people who are trying to contribute to this awesome community.

Comment: Fair enough. This is still a very low quality answer though.

Comment: Fair enough. I added some beef ;)